# iOS - NavigationBar hide/show

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, viewwillappear

I have a master `viewController` and many detail `viewController`. Master `viewController` doesn't have any `UINavigationBar` but detail `viewController` has `UINavigationBar`. So I have some problem. When I swipe from detailVC to masterVC `UINavigationBar` hiding in `detailVC`

Have you any solution this?

I use these methods (master `viewController` )

```
 -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

     [super viewWillAppear:animated];
     [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];

    }
```

(detail `viewController`)

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
     [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}
```

[image]

Comment: You don't need to handle it in this way, UINavigationController will do that for you.I think there is something wrong with you code.Can you show me how you push to detailVC from masterVC?

Comment: NoteTableViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"noteID"];
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

Comment: This is the code that push to detailVC

Comment: Yes, that's right. And the gif you provide work fine. What's wrong? The navigationController is used for this way to show a *stack* like hierarchy.

Comment: When swipe and break the detailVC. After several times navigationBar hide in detailVC. Then I have to relaunch the app because I cant across any vc

Comment: Did you add something inside (hide the navigationBar) the swipeGesturer method?

Comment: Unfortunately did not add anything inside the navigationBar

Comment: I have updated the gif. You can see the issue clearly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally

I have solved this issue.

I wrote UINavigationBar hiding code for firstVC in the viewDidAppear method.

> -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
>
> ```
>  [super viewDidAppear:animated];
>  [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
> ```
>
> }

[image]